# Images are not building on M1 Macbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, apple-m1, python-3.8

I was earlier using Macbook Intel and the project (which relies on multiple internal-external images) were working fine. But now when i try to build them, I get stuck at this line.

```
=> CACHED [api  1/18] FROM gcr.io/<gcp-project-name>/python-base:3.2-259@sha256:<sha256>                                                              0.0s
 => => resolve gcr.io/<gcp-project-name>/python-base:3.2-259@sha256:<sha256>                                                                           0.0s
 => [api internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                             0.6s
 => => transferring context: 36.30MB                                                                                                                                                                              0.6s
 => [api  2/18] RUN apt-get update     &&     apt-get upgrade -y --no-install-recommends     &&     apt-get install -y     graphicsmagick     imagemagick     pngnq     pngcrush     build-essential     xmlse  131.9s
```

I let it run for hours and it didn't move.

Before this, I was stuck at error that requested image doesn't meet the machine so i added following line to my docker-compose (for all images)

```yaml
  api:
    container_name: <image_name>
    platform: linux/amd64 <-- I added this line
    image: <appname>:latest
    build:
```

How can i debug whats going on and how can i move forward.

Comment: If you are on a M1 Macbook and using a container with `amd64` binaries, be aware that Docker actually uses `qemu` to emulate the runtime architecture of the container. This may very well have performance impacts. Regarding your error - I recommend simplifying your docker file and launching it manually with `docker run ...` and then attempting to install the dependencies manually. You may encounter errors when doing so that docker is otherwise not displaying.

Comment: Could you please share some details on what to simplify? the docker images require bunch of configs/env variable/volumes binding/, should all those be passed as `run` argument? how?

Comment: Provide your Dockerfile (ideally a minimal version that reproduces the issue) and I can tell you how to simplify it and test it. A Dockerfile just runs a bunch of code on your base Docker image for you so the container already has a certain configuration. You can always just use the base image directly without any of the other code in the Dockerfile. Then, you can launch a container of the image and run stuff like `apt update` manually. If you do this, you'll likely encounter the true reason your docker build is hanging.

Comment: I hate to say it because I don't want to come off as rude, but as it is there really isn't much anyone can do to help with your issue. If you could provide a [mre] with a minimal dockerfile that would be very useful. I happen to have a MX Macbook so I could try reproducing on my end. My best guess from the information you've provided is it's either an issue with `qemu` in the container, it's a network issue related to accessing the `apt` mirrors, and/or there is an error thrown inside the container that docker-compose isn't showing you.

Comment: Well you have given me enough pointers for time being. I will see how much i can share/debug by my own.